# How do I install and enable the English language pack on Firefox ESR?

Tags: linux, firefox

I'm using [Debian 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_9_(Stretch)) (Stretch/stable) with Firefox ESR 52.3.0 from the repositories. The only languages available for spellcheck are Spanish and German.

I tried to install the [English (US) language pack](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/english-us-language-pack/), but it's not compatible with this version of Firefox. I also installed `firefox-esr-l10n-en-gb`, the English (GB) language pack from the repositories, and restarted Firefox, but English still isn't available as a language.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this writing, the English (US) *language pack* is incompatible with Firefox ESR 52.3.0, but if your only concern is enabling English spellcheck, the [English spell checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/united-states-english-spellche/) *is* compatible with this version.

The dictionary files and language packs for all supported languages are available [on the language page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/). The English spell checker is the first "Install Dictionary" link under English (US) on that page.

Answer (score 1):

The language packs are packaged according to the Firefox version they're intended for. Since you're using Firefox 52.x and the latest version is for Firefox 55.x, you should click on *View other versions* (right below the grayed out *Add to Firefox* button), which will bring you to [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/english-us-language-pack/versions/) page.

You might have to scroll down a bit until you see the one with green *Add to Firefox* button.